# jTemplate processTemplate Callback

Tags: jquery, callback, jtemplate

When using jTemplate the callback function is never entered, what am i doing wrong?

```
updateTarget.processTemplate(tmpData, function() {
    console.log("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with jTemplates before. But after reading the [reference](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/doc/symbols/jQuery.fn.html#.processTemplate) of `processTemplate()` I saw no callback option, but there is one in the `processTemplateStart` method as the last parameter (options).

`processTemplateStart(url, param, interval, args, options)`

> **options**
>   options and callbacks

But I coudn't find any examples how to use it. But if you want to use `processTemplate` and execute code after it, then just simply add the code after the method.

```
updateTarget.processTemplate(tmpData);
console.log('Will be excecuted after the process template');
```

Comment: I have tried to use it after the template has been processed but it's not really working as I want it to. The idea is to use a jquery.selectBox() after the processTemplate is done to style the dropdownlists inside the template, but if i put that code after the process then the template has not had time to finish properly before I call the selectBox and so the dropdowns are not being styled. My intellisense is showing the option to have a callback function in the processTemplate but I have not seen any examples. Do you know what I can do to work around this issue if the callback doesn't work?

Comment: You can add an delay after the template method as an work-around. `setTimeout(function() { //the code that runs after the delay }, 300); //will run after 300 miliseconds`